# How much is known about isomorphism types of separable Stone spaces?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Countable Stone spaces have a reasonable classification up to homeomorphism: every such space is homeomorphic to some countable ordinal with the order topology. What about separable Stone spaces? How much is known about their homeomorphism types?

The only other kinds of separable Stone spaces i was able to think of were coproducts of a copy of the cantor space and a countable ordinal.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't expect there to be any nice classification.  The "universal" separable Stone space is $\beta\mathbb{N}$, the Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb{N}$, which can explicitly be described as the space of ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$ (aka the Stone space of the power set Boolean algebra $P(\mathbb{N})$).  Every separable Stone space is a quotient of $\beta\mathbb{N}$, but there are oodles of these.

For instance, given a finite subset $F\subset\beta\mathbb{N}$, you could consider the quotient space $\beta\mathbb{N}/F$ that collapses $F$ to a point.  There are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ different choices of $F$, and each $\beta\mathbb{N}/F$ is homeomorphic to $\beta\mathbb{N}/F'$ for only $2^{\aleph_0}$ different choices of $F'$ (proof sketch: assuming for simplicity that $F$ and $F'$ don't contain any principal ultrafilters, a homeomorphism $\beta\mathbb{N}/F\to \beta\mathbb{N}/F'$ restricts to a bijection between their isolated points, which is just a bijection $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ which turns the elements of $F$ into the elements of $F'$, so there is only one such $F'$ for each bijection $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$).  So, this gives $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ different separable Stone spaces up to homeomorphism.

Comment: That makes sense. All of those spaces you mentioned are of cardinality $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ right? Could there more hope if we add the restriction for our spaces to be of cardinality $\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$?

Comment: That's correct.  I would guess that restricting to cardinality $\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ wouldn't help much.  If you instead impose the stronger requirement that the space is second-countable and not just separable, though, then I think there is some hope.  (Then, for instance, you can say that any nonempty second-countable Stone space without isolated points is homeomorphic to the Cantor set, and get a handle on the possibilities if there are isolated points through the Cantor-Bendixson theorem.)

Answer (score 1):

In your coproduct construction the countable ordinal is a closed subset. There are some different kinds of examples associated to a Cantor set $C$ and a countable limit ordinal $\alpha$, where you remove the limit point of $\alpha$ to get the subspace $\alpha'$, and then you put a topology on the Cantor set union $\alpha'$ so that $\alpha'$ is open and the limit set of $\alpha'$ is any chosen closed subset of the Cantor set.

Comment: Nice example. I believe you mean remove the limit point from $\alpha+1$ tho, right?

Comment: Regarding $\alpha$ versus $\alpha+1$, my answer is written using the association, to each countable ordinal $\alpha$, of a compact topological space, namely all ordinals $\le \alpha$ with the order topology. It sounds like you are thinking of replacing $\le \alpha$ with $< \alpha$, but that loses compactness. Frankly I'm not sure what the standard is, though.